# iPhone Draw Line Thickness

Tags: iphone, line, thickness

My line is only 1 pixel thick. How can I thicken it? I use MontoTouch.net but Objective-C is fine in the answer.

```
ctx.SetRGBStrokeColor (1,1,1, 1f);
ctx.MoveTo(130,110);
ctx.AddLineToPoint(200,200);
ctx.StrokePath();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ctx.LineWidth = 5;`